# Numeric digitise icon not in digitise bar

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mac

I am using QGIS 2.4 on Mac Os.  I have the Numeric digitise plungin installed but it does not appear in the Digitise Tool Bar.  I have tried reinstalling it but it makes no difference.  I have used it in the past but not often so I have no idea when it disappeared.

Comment: I have just installed qgis 2.14 and that did not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it would appear that upgrading did fix this!  I can confirm that numeric digitise works in 2.14 *and* gives you a choice of CRS for you points which really helps me!