# QGIS Numerical Digitize button always greyed out?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Trying to use Numerical Digitize 0.3.0 in QGIS 2.18.15. I have both that plugin and Numerical Vertex Edit installed, and I can see both icons (greyed) on the Digitize toolbar.

I create a new point layer, enable editing, and click the Add Feature button. Both of these buttons remain grey and unclickable.

I realise that this isn't a support site for these plugins, but am I doing something wrong? If not, we may want to address the fact that use of these plugins is the accepted solution for a number of other questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin works with projected coordinates. It does not work in geographic coordinates.

When I used geographic coordinates, the plugin grayed out, but when I used projected coordinates (UTM for example), it works well. Therefore, you need to change the CRS of your data from geographic to meter projection.

[image]

Here is the tool window:

[image]

Comment: On the other hand, this answer implies that it was working some time later: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/206880/17162

Comment: @Flyto I updated my answer, and I found the solution.